# Webpage not loading images from cloudfront

Tags: html, amazon-cloudfront

So I am adding an image tag on my webpage like this:

```
<img src="http://d1vbshjhi899db.cloudfront.net/ads/photos/000/014/677/square/ad.jpg?1405869886" height="100%" width="100%">
```

The image shows up perfectly when entered in the browser, but it will not load in my image tag.
To make it clear, I have tried putting an image there which i found on google, that works fine, but when it comes to cloudfront, it just will not load.

Is there anything fishy I have to do when working with cloudfront or what may be the problem?

Edit:

The problem was that I was using an AdBlocker that for some reason blocked the images to be viewed on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that the problem was not within either the code or cloudfront. The problem was within chrome. Everything works fine in Safari.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `?1405869886` from your `src`. Check that none of your CSS might be affecting your `img` element or its containing element.

Comment: ?1405869886 does not make any difference. CSS should not affect my img, as I noted, I've tried with other images from google. :/